# How can I restore a postgresql db dump from a local db to a server via psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have building and testing a psql database on my local machine, and the time is come to move it to a server. I have my dump file, but I'm not sure how to actually get it on the server to restore it there. Obviously something like the following doesn't work:

```
psql -U user -d datbase < C:/dbbackups/dbbackup.dump
```

But what is the proper way to get my dump on the server from my local to properly restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pg_dump`.

```sh
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```

If you want to use your dump you could of course also transfer your dump file over to the new server securly using e.g. [`SFTP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) and then restore it there as you would on your local machine.